# Safari clear cache on quit

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Is there any way of convincing Safari to clear the cache when it quits? If not from Safari's options, then maybe an extension that does this?

I would use private browsing instead, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work well for me (some sites say they can't use cookies, and a lot of functionality is broken with this enabled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menubar app Cookie can clear exactly what you want to clear at quit, at timed intervals, or both.

Can also clear thosenefarious Tracking Cookies, as well as non-favorite cookies, Flash and other databases -- and do this for all your browsers.

Not part of the company--just think especially with Tracking, it's a must have. [SweetPea Productions](http://sweetpproductions.com), trial available.

Answer (score 2):

You could [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
osascript -e 'quit app "Safari"'
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Metadata/Safari/History
rm -rf ~/Library/Safari/Databases
rm -f ~/Library/Safari/Form\ Values
rm -f ~/Library/Safari/Downloads.plist
rm -f ~/Library/Safari/History.plist
rm -f ~/Library/Safari/HistoryIndex.plist
rm -f ~/Library/Safari/LastSession.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/Safari/LocalStorage
rm -rf ~/Library/Safari/TopSites.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/Safari/WebpageIcons.db
rm -rf ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Safari.savedState
```

It doesn't remove:

- Preferences stored in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
- Bookmarks
- Information stored in keychains
- Extensions or their settings
- Notification warnings (~/Library/Safari/UserNotificationPermissions.plist)
- Location warnings (~/Library/Safari/LocationPermissions.plist)

I used dtrace to check which files were opened or deleted when I used the Reset Safari dialog.

```
sudo opensnoop -n Safari
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::unlink:entry{printf("%u %s %s",pid,execname,copyinstr(arg0));}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the *Develop* menu to clear the cache if you don't want to clear your history.

From your Safari menu bar click **Safari > Preferences**, then select the *Advanced* tab, then *Show Develop menu in menu bar*.

Now, from the menu bar click **Develop >  Empty Caches** or use the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a working free option:

Safari Cleaner (applescript): http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=38244

Download from sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/safaricleaner/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good idea to scribble in system files directly. Let's do this job by Safari by automated action:

```
# clear cache and history of safari
# LB 10'2016 Ver 05

set SafariQuit to false # say to Safari good bye if we want

tell application "Safari" to activate # a good way to start safari without cookies
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    set frontmost to true

    click (menu item "Verlauf löschen …" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Verlauf" of menu bar 1)

    if exists sheet 1 of front window then # check, if safari is runnung without of window
        click button "Verlauf löschen" of sheet 1 of front window
    else
        click button "Verlauf löschen" of front window
        set SafariQuit to true # safari is running without window and also not used actually
    end if
end tell

if SafariQuit then
    tell application "Safari"
        quit
    end tell
end if

# accessibility Inspector.app (Xcode)
# http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2012/04/accessibility-inspector/
```

Make'n App from this, add a nice "Safari in Waste".icns, put it in the dock and have fun. Don't forget to give this new App the rights to act in

```
system|safety|privacy|helper.
```

Comment: This script works now for Safari Version 10.0 (11602.1.50.0.10)